# How to add tags to an S3 Bucket without deleting the existing tags using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, s3-bucket

I am using this function:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging(bucket)
Set_Tag = bucket_tagging.put(Tagging={'TagSet':[{'Key':'Owner', 'Value': owner}]})
```

It is deleting the existing tags and I can see only one tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use the following

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging('bucket_name')
tags = bucket_tagging.tag_set
tags.append({'Key':'Owner', 'Value': owner})
Set_Tag = bucket_tagging.put(Tagging={'TagSet':tags})
```

This gets the existing tags, adds a new one, and then puts them all back in.

Comment: What would be the solution if the existing tag set contains tags with 'aws:' prefix?
It gives error 'An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateTags operation: Value ( aws:cloudformation:stack-name ) for parameter key is invalid. Tag keys starting with 'aws:' are reserved for internal use'.

Comment: Do you need to keep that tag in there? If not you could always add a line before appending that removes all the keys with the aws prefix. Or if you do need them you could rename them by removing the aws prefix.

Comment: How do you solve the problem of concurrent attempts to add tags conflicting? If both people read and then both people write, the last write will clobber the other one.

Comment: interfect, what is your situation that you have multiple people trying to add tags to S3 buckets?

Comment: !! WARNING !! bucket_tagging.tag_set will raise if there are no tags.

Comment: This approach can work in there are existing tags (exists) and the new key does not exist in that TagSet already.  Check for existing TagSet and that the key does not exist.  Another step could be remove the pre-existing key if that is desired.

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same problem and solved it with my own method:

```
import boto3

def set_object_keys(bucket, key, update=True, **new_tags):
    """
    Add/Update/Overwrite tags to AWS S3 Object

    :param bucket_key: Name of the S3 Bucket
    :param update: If True: appends new tags else overwrites all tags with **kwargs
    :param new_tags: A dictionary of key:value pairs 
    :return: True if successful 
    """

    #  I prefer to have this var outside of the method. Added for completeness
    client = boto3.client('s3')   

    old_tags = {}

    if update:
        old = client.get_object_tagging(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Key=key,
        )

        old_tags = {i['Key']: i['Value'] for i in old['TagSet']}

    new_tags = {**old_tags, **new_tags}

    response = client.put_object_tagging(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=key,
        Tagging={
            'TagSet': [{'Key': str(k), 'Value': str(v)} for k, v in new_tags.items()]
        }
    )

    return response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200
```

And you add your tags in the function call:

```
set_object_keys(....., name="My Name", colour="purple")
```

This will add new tags and update existing ones

Comment: Awesome solution! This is the solution I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a good solution to a different problem. The OP is interested in "bucket tagging", whereas this is an answer for "object tagging".

Answer (score 1):

## ================ Bucket Level Tagging ================

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='default')
client = session.client('s3', 'ap-southeast-2')

def set_bucket_tags(bucket, update=True, **new_tags):
    old_tags = {}

    if update:
        try:
            old = client.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucket)
            old_tags = {i['Key']: i['Value'] for i in old['TagSet']}
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("There was no tag")

    new_tags = {**old_tags, **new_tags}

    response = client.put_bucket_tagging(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Tagging={
            'TagSet': [{'Key': str(k), 'Value': str(v)} for k, v in new_tags.items()]
        }
    )

    print(response)
```

## You can tag as many as you want [as many accepted by AWS]

set_bucket_tags("selim.online", True, key1="value1", key2="value2", key3="value3")

Comment: I couldn't get it to work using the example provided. Plus what if the key needs quotes because of colon or dash names?